# A small table join large table on like, using impala

Tags: sql, join, impala

An impala query as below runs very slow.

```
SELECT pattern, MAX(time) 
  FROM (SELECT t.time, p.pattern 
          FROM t 
          JOIN p 
            ON (t.name LIKE p.pattern)) AS tmp 
 GROUP BY pattern
```

**p** is large of 1billion records, and **t** is small of only 1 record.

How can I optimize this? This is actually a nested loop join, but why did this take about half an hour to complete?

What's more, when I use the following query

```
SELECT time 
  FROM p 
 WHERE name LIKE 'one_pattern' 
 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

It only takes 3s. I am really confused.

Comment: You probably cannot optimize this, at least not easily.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thx! But as far as I'm concerned, the small table will be read into memory, and then it scan the large table. Is this true?  And is this the core efficiency bottleneck?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually, I test with a small table only with one record, and large table with 1billion. It took about half an hour.  Should it be of that slow?

Comment: . . It takes time to scan a billion rows and apply a `like` pattern.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But as for the second query, it also did a full table scan, did it?

Comment: You would have to look at the execution plan.  A pattern with no wildcards can behave quite differently from a more complex pattern.